# Which files should be commited in SVN for an Angular project?

Tags: angular, eclipse, svn

creating a project based on Angular as the frontend results on many automatically generated files. I would like to commit the project into SVN including the necessary files only.

Below is the current frontend folders structure:

[image: Current frontend folders' structure]

Which files/folders should be commited in SVN ?

Comment: except node_modules and node  all others folders you can commit

Comment: Also `dist` don't need commit.

Comment: I've just tried to create a new project (IDE eclipse) with the same files as displayed above but without the folders "node_modules", "node" and "dist", but each time a dependency error is displayed.

Comment: @Sakr did you run `npm install` to install all the dependencies specified in package.json?

Comment: @Jette yes indeed, so the node_modules folder doesn't have to be checked in. The depencies will be installed via npm install using the definded packages from "package.json"

Answer (score 1):

Indeed as mentioned by Robert and Stepan, the following folders could/should be ignored:

- node
- node_modules
- dist